# C# MySQL library: How can I reduce bundling and abstraction?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm a teen developer who just does this as a hobby, but I still care about good practice even if I don't fully understand it. Two of the most used phrases when sharing the code of my C# MySQL library is bundling and abstraction,

First of all... do I need to reduce said phrases? If so, how can I do that? Among any other general recommendations on areas, I can improve.

DatabaseProvider: This simply just holds state for database settings (host, name, port, etc) and returns a new instance of `DatabaseConnection` whenever the application needs one.

```
public class DatabaseProvider : IDatabaseProvider
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DatabaseProvider(string databaseName, string password, uint port, string host, string username)
    {
        _connectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Database = databaseName,
            Password = password,
            Port = port,
            Server = host,
            UserID = username,
            SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None,
            DefaultCommandTimeout = 30,
            CharacterSet = "utf8mb4",
            AllowUserVariables = true,
            MinimumPoolSize = 1,
        }.ToString();
    }

    public DatabaseConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        
        return new DatabaseConnection(connection, command);
    }
}
```

DatabaseConnection: Also pretty simple, although very different from the provider. This is the actual abstracted instance of `MySqlConnection` with utility methods to perform frequent operations like fetching rows or collections of rows or just running general queries. It also supports parameters although they aren't type-safe.

```
public class DatabaseConnection : IDisposable
{
    private readonly MySqlConnection _connection;
    private readonly MySqlCommand _command;

    public DatabaseConnection(MySqlConnection connection, MySqlCommand command)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _command = command;

        _connection.Open();
    }

    public void SetQuery(string commandText)
    {
        _command.Parameters.Clear();
        _command.CommandText = commandText;
    }

    public void ExecuteQuery()
    {
        _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public DataTable ExecuteTable()
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        using var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(_command);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);

        return dataTable;
    }

    public DataRow ExecuteRow()
    {
        DataRow dataRow = null;

        var dataSet = new DataSet();

        using (var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(_command))
        {
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }

        if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            dataRow = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        }

        return dataRow;
    }

    public void AddParameter(string name, object value)
    {
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }

        _connection.Dispose();
        _command.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the complaints about too much abstraction or not enough? Are you aware of the .net Entity Framework for databases that works with SQL server or MySQL?

Comment: Well the complaints are usually to do with too much boilerplate so I would say not enough. I've heard of various frameworks and ORMs although they all seem overkill for what I want to do.

Comment: Could you please provide the using statements for the 2 classes you show here such as `using System.Data;` and `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`. This will help us review the code.